# Process cxf request with amq

Tags: soap, apache-camel, cxf, activemq-classic, jbossfuse

I want to make such a solution:

1. cxf https soap service gets a request and sends it to activemq queue
   1
2. service  implementation gets message from queue 1, process it and
       puts to queue 2
3. endpoint  gets response from queue 2 and sends
       response to a client

Now, I came with a kind of a solution but I'm not sure how to process response from activemq and send back as SOAP response. My camel blueprints below. Endpoint blueprint:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
           xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/bindings/soap"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
             http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
             http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0 http://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-cm/blueprint-cm-1.0.0.xsd
             http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
             http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd
             http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/bindings/soap http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/blueprint/soap.xsd">
    <bean id="cardServiceEndpoint" class="com.endpoint.card.CardEndpoint">
        <argument>
            <reference interface="com.card.CardService" />
        </argument>
    </bean>
    <cxf:cxfEndpoint
        id="cardEndpoint" 
        address="https://host:port/soa/card"
        serviceClass="com.card.CardService">
        <cxf:properties>
            <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
        </cxf:properties>
    </cxf:cxfEndpoint>
    <bean id="jaxB" class="org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.JaxbDataFormat">
        <property name="prettyPrint" value="true" />
        <property name="contextPath" value="com.type.card" />
    </bean>
    <camelContext id="endpoint-card-cxf" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="endpoint-soap-in">
            <from uri="cxf:bean:cardEndpoint"/>
            <transform>
                <simple>${body[0]}</simple>
            </transform>
            <marshal ref="jaxB"/>
            <setHeader headerName="JMSType">
                <simple>${headers.operationName}</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="amq:q.in"/>
        </route>
        <route id="endpoint-soap-out">
            <from uri="amq:q.out" />
            <unmarshal ref="jaxB" />
            <!-- STUCK HERE :( -->
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

Service processor blueprint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
             http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
             http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0 http://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-cm/blueprint-cm-1.0.0.xsd
             http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">
    <bean id="cardService" class="com.card.impl.DefaultCardService">
        <argument>
            <reference interface="com.base.StashService"/>
        </argument>
    </bean>
    <service interface="com.card.CardService" ref="cardService" />
    <bean id="amqCardServiceEndpoint" class="com.card.endpoint.AmqCardEndpoint">
        <argument ref="cardService" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jaxB" class="org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.JaxbDataFormat">
        <property name="prettyPrint" value="true" />
        <property name="contextPath" value="com.type.base:com.type.card" />
    </bean>
    <camelContext id="service-card-cx" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="card-rq-broker">
            <from uri="amq:queue:q.in?asyncConsumer=true" />
            <unmarshal ref="jaxB" />
            <doTry>
                <bean ref="amqCardServiceEndpoint" method="invoke" />
                <doCatch>
                    <exception>com.type.base.BaseException</exception>
                    <setBody>
                        <simple>${exception.getFaultInfo()}</simple>
                    </setBody>
                </doCatch>
            </doTry>
            <marshal ref="jaxB" />
            <to uri="amq:q.out" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

Any help or advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `jmsReplyTo` to specify the name of the reply queue (if you want a fixed queue name) that Camel should use for listening for the response. See more about request/reply on the Camel JMS documentation.

```
<to uri="amq:q.in?jmsReplyTo=q.out"/>
// continue here when reply is back
```

- http://camel.apache.org/jms

Comment: Hi, Claus, thanks for a reply! I can read message from q.out, I'm not sure how to send it back to client who initiated SOAP request..

Comment: @IDeveloper, you don't have to send it back. Just do as Claus said and add whatever processing you need after `<to uri="amq:q.in?jmsReplyTo=q.out"/>`. Whatever is set as the exchange body at the end of your route will be used as a response to your WS. Looking at your blueprint I'd say you can remove the "endpoint-soap-out" route and instead just add `<unmarshal ref="jaxB" />` at the end of the "endpoint-soap-in" route.

Comment: @noMad17 hi, thanks for an explanation. I tried that approach, but it seems the message is lost atfer `<to uri="amq:q.in?jmsReplyTo=q.out"/>`. If I put a `<log message="body: ${body}" />` right after `to` node - nothing happens..

Comment: Make sure that the `ExchangePattern` is set to `InOut` before sending the message to your queue. Also make sure that the route which is consuming from the queue actually is receiving a message.

Comment: @noMad17 route which is consuming from the `q.in` is working correct. Now I receive a warning `Reply received for unknown correlationID [id_here] on reply destination [queue://q.out]`